# Generate switch-case from function definitions at compile time

Tags: c++, compile-time

I have a large list of functions that have all the same parameter signature:

```
SKString Login(SKString requestAsJson, const SKAppActionsInterface& appIface)
SKString SimulateUser(SKString requestAsJson, const SKAppActionsInterface& appIface)
SKString ResetSimulatedUser(SKString requestAsJson, const SKAppActionsInterface& appIface)
...
```

In another function, i call these functions in a big switch statement:

```
switch (request->Action)
{
case RequestAction::Login:
  return Login(requestAsJson, appIface);
case RequestAction::SimulateUser:
  return SimulateUser(requestAsJson, appIface);
case RequestAction::ResetSimulatedUser:
  return ResetSimulatedUser(requestAsJson, appIface);
...
}
```

Everything is in the same c++ file.

I wonder if i can somehow automatically generate the code of the switch statement at compile time?

I would like to write some macro for writing the function definition head:

```
REQUEST_FUNCTION(Login)
{
  //implementation here
}
```

that should generate the right function head (easy) but also add the name to some compile time container.

Then it could be possible to iterate over the compile time container to generate the various case blocks.

Is this possible and how?
Using C++11.

Comment: But... why not use a `map<RequestAction, std::funcion<SKString(SKSTring, const SKAppActionsInterface&)>>`? The whole idea of the switch seems wrong. Why not just make `request->Action` a function pointer and just `request->Action(requestAsJson, appIface);` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Because theoretically the switch might get a nicer code generated than the `map`. Since you know the entire set of values, you can generate a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). However, until the OP confirms that this is the case, I agree that it's a better idea.

Comment: Or just create a class with virtual operator () function and inherit from it and instantiate one of derivative classes upon registering "action"? `get a nicer code` - then I think a function pointer will get you the "nicest" code, there is no need for hashing, but for that we would need to know how exactly is "request->Action" used.

Comment: what ever you do, at least you need to spell out the name of the function to be called and the corresponding `RequestAction` to establish the mapping. I dont think this can be done much more concise and readable than with the switch you have. Macros are a possibility, but the price (obscure unreadable code) is too high in this case imho

Comment: You can make a `constexpr std::array<SKString(*)(SKString, const SKAppActionsInterface&), N> function_array;` and call it like `function_array[static_cast<unsigned>(request->Action)](requestAsJson, appIface);`. You will still need to list the enum->function mapping though.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, maybe with a macro you can leverage the fact that each Action enum value has the same name of the corresponding function, but I agree, the obscuration given by a macro make the things much worse than current code

Comment: @KamilCuk: I'm not against using a function pointer map. That sounds fine. Just how would i fill the map at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

This code does not generate the function head, but you can use it to generate the switch statement:

```
// List of function names
#define FUNCTIONS_LIST(f) \
    f(Login) \
    f(SimulateUser)

// Generate prototype of each function
#define GENERATE_PROTOTYPE(fname) \
    SKString fname (SKString requestAsJson, const SKAppActionsInterface& appIface);

// Generate switch case of each function
#define GENERATE_SWITCH(fname) \
    case RequestAction:: fname: \
        return fname(requestAsJson, appIface);

// Generate prototypes:
FUNCTIONS_LIST(GENERATE_PROTOTYPE)

// Generate switch:
void f() {
    switch (request->Action)
    {
    FUNCTIONS_LIST(GENERATE_SWITCH)
    }
}
```

One option to generate the function bodies is to add a second argument to `FUNCTIONS_LIST`. But this is quite unreadable.

```
#define FUNCTIONS_LIST(f) \
    f(Login, return "yes";) \
    f(SimulateUser, return "no";)

#define GENERATE_BODY(fname, fbody) \
    SKString fname (SKString requestAsJson, const SKAppActionsInterface& appIface) { fbody } 

// Second parameter is unused here
#define GENERATE_SWITCH(fname, fbody) \
    case RequestAction:: fname: \
        return fname(requestAsJson, appIface);

FUNCTIONS_LIST(GENERATE_BODY)
```